# App development with database and midi streaming.

Tags: android, database, streaming

I'm looking for some general information about an app idea I wish to proceed with, I don't know too much about how apps work with databases and so forth so if I'm incorrect please inform me.

Basically what I'm looking for is to design an app that would play midi files. Let's say I have 100 midi files and all I would like the app to do is play them. To me the best idea I have is to make a database for all of the midi files, and then to have the app access the database to load what is stored. I want the user to be able to browse through the midis on the server and have an option to stream or download the file. The app is generally simple, but I'm not sure exactly how to structure a database to fit this need. Any ideas tips and other info would be more than welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the official documentation for [SQLDatabase](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). It may help you.

In your case, you should probably have a few columns in your database for each midi file to play, like for example :

- id
- name
- download state (in cache or not)
- file uri on server (for remote play or download)
- local uri (cached file when already downloaded)

Answer (score 0):

What info do you have about the files? You could also store this info in a text file if that seems simpler for you.

You could just user MediaPlayer to play them based on the url/filename and then display the track info.